# clang-format converts template to bit shift

Tags: c++, c++98, clang-format

I am using clang-format to format C++ code. I have the following form,

```
std::vector<std::bitset<32> >(32,0)
```

After formatting it becomes,

```
std::vector<std::bitset<32>>(32,0)
```

Which causes errors when compiling for C++98. Is there a workaround this issue?

Comment: You can use the `-style` option to override a few specific formatting rules. Use it to override the rules for nested templates.

Comment: Check that the `Cpp11BracedListStyle` format option is set to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clang format supports [options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), including `SpacesInAngles` which -- if set to true -- should fix this. There is also a `Standard` option, which can be used to specify the version of C++ that the formatting must be compatible with, which will imply the relevant options for that version of C++.

In other words, using:

```
Standard: Cpp03
```

... will set this correctly for the pre-C++11 formatting.

Comment: No idea... you''ll have to report back, @HappyCoder